# Dsquery group –name A* --> dsquery failed:'A*' is an unknown parameter

Tags: windows, active-directory

From here:

http://ss64.com/nt/dsquery-group.html

```
Examples

Find all groups on the current domain with a name that starts with 'Admin'

C:\> dsquery group -name Admin*

Find all groups in the 'Groups' OU

C:\> dsquery group ou=Groups,ou=AcmeCo,dc=ss64,dc=com
```

When I try it I get the following error:

```
C:\>Dsquery group –name A*
dsquery failed:'A*' is an unknown parameter.
type dsquery /? for help.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two different types of hyphens and I used the wrong one on the "-name" parameter.

Why it said the wrong parameter is 'A*' remains a mystery, as does why "net group /domain SOME_GROUP_I_KNOW_EXISTS" fails also.